# What are subprocesses in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to know what subprocesses in python means? Is it similar to interfaces in Java or is it a completely different topic?

I have read that it is a replacement for older modules such as `os.system
os.spawn*
os.popen*
popen2.*
commands.*` 
But still not able to get the exact and explanatory tutorial on the same.

Where are they exactly used in?

Comment: But, its certainly a doubt clearing site for sure.

Comment: @user1162512 No, it is not.

Answer (score 4):

To create subprocesses!

This is an *operating system* (OS) concept, and has nothing to do with Java interfaces.

Your OS controls *processes*, like your python program. With the `subprocess` module it is easy to ask the OS to create more such processes, and communicate with them.

Processes are controlled in a hierarchy, a tree structure of parents and children. There is *one* master process that started with the OS kernel when your computer booted, and everything else is either a direct subprocess of that master process, or a indirect child process.

The module provides a higher-level API to do this than the lower-level, direct translations of the C-API functions `os.system`, `os.spawn*`, etc. with more flexibility and safety against security problems.

Answer (score 1):

Subprocesses are the same in Python as they are in any other languages.

As you can read from [the module's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), it can (and should) be used to spawn other programs and control their input or output.

For example, if you want to compute the SHA1 sum of a data stream, you can fork off a subprocess calling the `sha1sum` binary, give the data to its stdin, close it and read the result out of stdout. (There are better ways to do this; it just serves as an example.)

This module is favourited over `os.system` and the other related functions as it provides more safety, flexibility and ease to use.

Comment: Well that just the copy&pasted material from the documentation itself. I have read this earlier as well, but was not able to understand and thats why posted it on SO. and you are providing with the same copy pasted material

Comment: @user1162512 Maybe then explain what it is you don't understand? The documentation is pretty clear.

Comment: @user1162512 I did not copy&paste, I did explain what they write there. If that is not clear enough, please tell us what exactly you don't understand.